# HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse Using CookieContainer Not Logging In

Tags: .net, cookies, authentication, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

Spent a good part of the evening on this and can't figure out what's wrong. The data gets posted to the login page and gets processed just fine - a wrong login/pwd comes up as an error page, and a successful one gets a blank response with a "Location" header. However, trying to go there or any other protected page throws back the login page. I figure I must be missing some minor thing somewhere. Below is the complete code less the actual user/pwd of course. I hope someone's got some idea of what's wrong :)

```
$class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            var username = "user";
            var password = "pwd";

            // LOGIN
            Console.WriteLine("Logging in...");

            var postData = string.Format("username={0}&password={1}&remote=&action=auth&submit=Login&from=", username, password);
            var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://freedns.afraid.org/zc.php");
            req.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentLength = postData.Length;
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            // This is necessary to capture cookies
            // The response will contain a "Location" header for redirect
            req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

            req.KeepAlive = true;
            req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1) ; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)";

            var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            var loginDataBytes = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
            req.ContentLength = loginDataBytes.Length;
            var stream = req.GetRequestStream();
            stream.Write(loginDataBytes, 0, loginDataBytes.Length);

            var webResp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

            var datastream = webResp.GetResponseStream();
            if (datastream == null) { throw new Exception("Data stream is null."); }

            var reader = new StreamReader(datastream);
            var response = reader.ReadToEnd();

            if (response.IndexOf("Invalid UserID/Pass") != -1) { throw new Exception("Invalid user/password."); }
            if (response.IndexOf("must enable cookies") != -1) { throw new Exception("Cookies not enabled."); }

            // ACCESS PAGE
            Console.WriteLine("Accessing page...");

            req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://freedns.afraid.org/dynamic/");
            req.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
            req.Method = "GET";
            req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1) ; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)";

            webResp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

            datastream = webResp.GetResponseStream();
            if (datastream == null) { throw new Exception("No response received."); }

            reader = new StreamReader(datastream);
            response = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(response);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you do a web request, it is separate from what you access through your browser. So if you log in using the web request, it is only valid inside the web request. When you make a request through browser, you still need to login.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string)` in order to post special characters such as `!@#$%^&*()_+<>?:;"'{[}]|\`

You will need to add this as a reference to the project as well as referencing it in the namespace.

Comment: Referance for HTTP Utility is System.Web